# How to skip Invalid Email Ids in Postfix and prevent it from throwing error

Tags: jakarta-mail, postfix-mta

I am using postfix in my linux server to send emails.I have an usecase where one of the application using Java Mail uses postfix to send emails.

Sometimes the application send invalid email ids.Validating email ids in the application side is a solution,but I am curious if we can do that using postfix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can activate/configure postfix ability of *address_verification* (see also http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_VERIFICATION_README.html) to block unknown sender.